# Problem with code to show ads to search engine visitors only

Tags: php, wordpress, search, plugins, cookies

There is a plugin (for wordpress) to show ads to search engine visitors only.. a person was able to modify it
but the code only shows ads if you land and click another page...but it doesnt appear on the landing page. Can anyone help me know whats wrong on the code?

```
function wp_ozh_wsa_is_fromsearchengine($doset = false) {
global $wp_ozh_wsa;
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$yes = false;
if (isset($wp_ozh_wsa['my_search_engines'])) {
    $SE = $wp_ozh_wsa['my_search_engines'];
} else {
    $SE = array('/search?', 'images.google.', 'web.info.com', 'search.', 'del.icio.us/search',
    'soso.com', '/search/', '.yahoo.',
    );
}
foreach ($SE as $url) {
    if (strpos($ref,$url)!==false) {
        if ($doset) {
            $url = parse_url(get_option('home'));
            setcookie('wsas', 'yes', time() + 60*60, $url['path'] . '/');
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['wsas'])) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stated in the ref for [setcookie on php.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Once the cookies have been set, they
>   can be accessed on the next page load
>   with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS
>   arrays.

Simple fix, just add the following to your foreach:

```
foreach ($SE as $url) {
    if (strpos($ref,$url)!==false) {
        if ($doset) {
            $url = parse_url(get_option('home'));
            setcookie('wsas', 'yes', time() + 60*60, $url['path'] . '/');
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand :( I want for the ad to come out when they land on the site..and keep coming out when they navigate the site..

Comment: oh ok wait..i just saw the difference

Comment: it didnt work :( now it doesn't even show the ad on the other pages.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem.  You'll want to move the if(isset) to before the foreach.  It's running the foreach either way, so it seems to be returning true before it gets to the statement that checks it.

Comment: this is anoher code that does  the same thing..and is still doesnt work for me $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$SE = array('/search?', 'images.google.', 'web.info.com', 'search.', 'del.icio.us/search', 'soso.com', '/search/', '.yahoo.');
foreach ($SE as $source) {
  if (strpos($ref,$source)!==false) {
    setcookie("sevisitor", 1, time()+3600, "/", ".mysite.com"); 
    $sevisitor=true;
  }
}
 
function fromasearchengine(){
  global $sevisitor;
  if ($sevisitor==true || $_COOKIE["sevisitor"]==1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Comment: <?php if (function_exists('fromasearchengine')) {
  if (fromasearchengine()) { ?>
    INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
<?php } } ?>